# Error while running the HTTP adapter in IBM Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have created an HTTP adapter to call a procedure to add 2 numbers. Its a basic program to send input and display the output. Below is my code.

**HTML:**

```
First Integer: <input type="text" id="firstint"/>
Second Integer: <input type="text" id="secondint"/>
<input type="button" onclick="submitInput()" value="Submit"/>
```

**DemoHTTPAdapter-impl.js :**

```
    function submitInput() {
        var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'DemoHTTPAdapter',
            procedure : "getDemoAdd",
            parameters : [$('#firstint').val(),$('#secondint').val()]
        };

        var options = {
            onSuccess : success,
            onFailure : failure
        };

        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
    }

function getDemoAdd(firstint, lastint) {
    return {
        result : com.ibm.demo.DemoAdd.addTwoInteger(firstint,secondint)
    }
}
```

The procedure is invoked through a java code as below in the DemoAdd.java:

```
package com.ibm.demo;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DemoAdd {  
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DemoAdd.class.getName());

public static int addTwoInteger(int afirstInt, int aSecondInt) {        
    logger.info("Add Method Invoked with Parameter " + afirstInt + " & " + aSecondInt);
    return (afirstInt + aSecondInt);
}
```

I am getting an error when I run the html.

> submitInput() not defined.

whereas I have already defined the submitInput() method.

Answer (score 0):

You've placed your `submitInput` function inside the adapter implementation file (DemoHTTPAdapter-impl.js) instead of in your common\js\main.js file.

You need to differentiate between the adapter scope, which resides on the Worklight Server and thus you cannot call it directly, to the application scope which resides in the application itself.

Because they are of different scopes, the parser tries to find `submitInput`, but cannot find it.

The application's JavaScript needs to call the Worklight framework in order to send the request to the server to invoke the adapter.

Move the following code to your main.js:

```
function submitInput() {
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'DemoHTTPAdapter',
        procedure : "getDemoAdd",
        parameters : [$('#firstint').val(),$('#secondint').val()]
    };

    var options = {
        onSuccess : success,
        onFailure : failure
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response! I am having an issue to display the value from the adapter. Like, if I want to display the addition of the integers from the java code on my HTML. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: First correct the above basic flaw in your application, then mark this question as answered because your comment is unrelated to the question asked here. Then first search stack overflow because the question of how to display the result of the adapter in the app has been asked a great many time.